# Remove fields in Behavior::beforeSave

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, behavior, cakephp-2.3

I prepare my simplest behavior in CakePHP, works perfeclty in 1.3.

Short description: 
I have form with five inputs (type file), but User add only two files (3 inputs are empty). My behavior remove these three fields in beforeSave and return true. But `debug();` of save/saveAll return always these there fields as incorecct.

In this example there is some a difference between 1.3 and 2.x (tested on 2.3)?

Answer (score -1):

This is because you're using beforeSave() and not beforeValidate().

But you should not need to unset these fields if you set up your validation rules properly, see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#allowempty

Comment: This look like the are input files are required, but flags 'required' and 'allowEmpty' don't helpful.